# Avoid having 2 identical entries in SQlAlchemy using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I need to find a way to alert the user that what he's introducing already exists in the database, I have a Flask application and a SQLAlchemy database, I'm also using Flask-WTF, 
I tried with a very precarious solution: I stored the data captured by the forms in variables and I was thinking of concatenating them and using a Query to search if they exist.

```
nombre1 = form.nombre_primero.data
nombre2 = form.nombre_segundo.data
```

Anyway I think this is not the most appropriate way to handle the situation.

does Flask has some way to do this? Or would you recommend me something? 
I'd grateful if you could help me!

Comment: You didn't show your model, but maybe setting the field to unique will do?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by creating a composite unique constraint made of the select fields in the sqlalchemy model.

The table can be configured additionally via [`__table_args__` class property of the declarative base](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html).

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint

class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre_primero = db.Column(db.String(64))
    nombre_segundo = db.Column(db.String(64))

    __table_args__ = (
      UniqueConstraint('nombre_primero', 'nombre_segundo', name='uix_1'),
      )
```

You can write the data to the table and handle what exception is raised when there is a conflict.

Comment: I haven't considered this option because the table represents  patients and their infomation, there may be duplicate names or surnames, but the combination of all of them must be unique, that is why I need to find a way to control the combination of these  4 fields name1, name2, surname1, surname2

Comment: The unique constraint is when created as a composite uses the combined uniqueness of the composite fields in the table

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there is a simple way to solve this, at the table itself, you make a condition that rejects duplicate entries based on some condition which you define.

So one easy way you can do this is make a hybrid function. 
Read more about [Hybrid Attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) here.
`from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property`

Now where you make the model for your table, 
eg:

```
class xyz(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'xyz'
  #tablevalues defined here

  @hybrid_property
  def xyz()
    #make a method here which rejects duplicate entries.
```

Once you read the documentation you will understand how this works. 
I cant directly solve your problem because there isn't much information you have provided. But in this way, you can check the entries and make some method EASILY where your data is checked to be unique in anyway you want.